# Appendix reference numbers and titles

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, chapters, appendices

My issue is related to adding the Appendix using `\chapter`. I am defining Appendix as follows:

```
\chapter{My Appendix Title} % Main appendix title
\label{AppendixTemplate} 
% My Appendix content here.
```

Calling it in the main.tex using

```
\appendix
\input{Appendices/Appendix/AppendixTemplate}
```

Referring it in any other chapter like

```
the system is further detailed in Appendix~\ref{app:AppendixTemplate}
```

Now Questions:

1. the TOC only shows, "My Appendix Title" without Appendix A. I want it to be like "Appendix A. My Appendix Title".
2. In another chapter, where it is cited it output is "the system I further detailed in Appendix 1." It should be "the system I further detailed in Appendix A."

Comment: In order to get a helpful answer, it is normally encouraged to accompany your question with an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), even if to you it seems entirely obvious what you are asking without the MWE. In this case here, we really need to know what document class you are using ("standard", `book`, koma, `memoir` ...) and what modifications you are already applying to the TOC and references (`tocloft` ...) or even in general (full scale packages such as `classicthesis` and friends), as a lot of parameters depend on this details.

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE works for a book.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate filler text
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{72pt} % adds space for the word Appendix
 \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.} % if you want a period (or whatever punctuation after the appendix letter

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% \mainmatter % removed to shorten the example image
\section{Section Title} 
\lipsum[1]

\appendix
\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
\section{foo} 
\lipsum[1]

\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
\section{foo2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: table_of_contents_example]

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! But since this site is a Q&A site rather than a forum, it would have been preferred if you had edited your original post ("answer") to include this MWE instead of posting a new answer. Are you sure you need the `\gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}` twice?

Comment: @moewe, I tried the MWE after removing the second \gdef\thesection{Appendix \Alph[section}} line, and I got the desired result, so apparently it is not necessary, at least for the book documentclass. I was not able to edit my previous post---or perhaps when I tried, I did something wrong.